# Как убрать NaN при пустом значении input в live калькуляторе

Tags: javascript, html

При пустом значении выдаёт Nan.Вот сам код

```
<form name="ggg">
    <input class="babki" type="number" min="0" name="dengi" placeholder="Give" style="text-align:  center;">
  
    <input class="babki" readonly placeholder="Take your profit" style="float: right; text-align:  center; padding-top: 12px;color: #cdcdcd;" name="poluch">
</form>
    

<script>
    setInterval(function () {
      a = parseInt(document.ggg.dengi.value, 10);
      c = ((a * 10)/100) + a;
    document.ggg.poluch.value = c;
    }, 100);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  a = parseInt(+document.ggg.dengi.value, 10);
  c = ((a * 10) / 100) + a;
  document.ggg.poluch.value = c;
}, 100);
```

```html
<form name="ggg">
  <input class="babki" type="number" min="0" name="dengi" placeholder="Give" style="text-align:  center;">

  <input class="babki" readonly placeholder="Take your profit" style="float: right; text-align:  center; padding-top: 12px;color: #cdcdcd;" name="poluch">
</form>
```

---

При клике на кнопку:

```js
document.querySelector('#calc').addEventListener('click', el => {
  let a = parseInt(+document.ggg.dengi.value, 10);
  let c = ((a * 10) / 100) + a;
  document.ggg.poluch.value = c;
});
```

```html
<form name="ggg">
  <input class="babki" type="number" min="0" name="dengi" placeholder="Give" style="text-align:  center;">

  <input class="babki" readonly placeholder="Take your profit" style="float: right; text-align:  center; padding-top: 12px;color: #cdcdcd;" name="poluch">
  <input type="button" id="calc" value="GO!!!">
</form>
```

---

При тыках в инпуте:

```js
document.getElementById('give').addEventListener('input', updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
  let a = parseInt(+document.ggg.dengi.value, 10);
  let c = ((a * 10) / 100) + a;
  document.ggg.poluch.value = c;
}
```

```html
<form name="ggg">
  <input id="give" class="babki" type="number" min="0" name="dengi" placeholder="Give" style="text-align:  center;">

  <input id="take" class="babki" readonly placeholder="Take your profit" style="float: right; text-align:  center; padding-top: 12px;color: #cdcdcd;" name="poluch">  
</form>
```

Comment: А щас 0( Мне нужно чтобы было placeholder

Comment: @T1KO ну вы сами написали SetInterval, который сразу же после загрузки страницы начинает считать данные. Значит вам это надо делать при клике на кнопку. Выполнять функцию по подсчёту а интервал убирать. Тогда при загрузки страницы будет placeholder

Comment: а как-то через keyup

Comment: @T1KO см ответ в самом конце

Comment: а щас при удалении выдаёт 0

Comment: @T1KO если ноль - выводите плейсхолдер в коде, вот всё

Comment: Большое спасибо)